# How can I disable checkbox for multi value selection in react-dropdown-tree-select?

Tags: react-dropdown-tree-select

I am new to React and I stumbled upon react-dropdown-tree-select for a specific need I had allowing users to view data in Tree format for selection in DropDown. But, I want the users to only select 1 value at a time. How can i enforce that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such property available directly in react-dropdown-tree-select. But you can listen to `onChange` event and reset the entire data which you have passed in `data` props with the updated data with only one node selected.

Check the following code.

```
onChange = (currentNode) => {
  // keep reference of default data structure.
  const updatedData = this.props.defaultData;
  // find node related to currentData in your tree and set checked property
  this.setState({data : updatedData });  
}

render = () => {
 return (
    <DropdownTreeSelect
      data={this.state.data}
      onChange={this.onChange}
    />
  );
}
```

This will basically stop the user from selecting multiple options instead of disabling remainig item you are unselecting the previously selected items.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want one element selected at a time you can use mode="radioSelect"

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.